# Add Danish Dvorak keyboard layout to OSX

Tags: macos, dvorak

I'm trying to find a Danish Dvorak layout for OSX.  I can't find any non-English Dvorak layouts in the system settings or while poking around the Internet.

Is it possible to import the layout from one of the BSD or Linux distros? As a worst case, is it possible to create new keyboard layouts for OSX?

Comment: Have you tried using [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a custom layout?